# How to call onclick event on confirm message alert box?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using a javascript

```
function ValueChanged()
{           
    if (document.getElementById("<%=isDirty.ClientID %>").value != document.getElementById("<%=rdbQuestiontype.ClientID %>").value)     
    {

       if (window.confirm('Your changes are not saved. Do you want to save your changes before you exit.'))
           return false;
       else
           return true;
    }
}
```

this java script i am calling on `OnClientClick="return ValueChanged();`

I have a Save button on the same page i want to save the data when client click on OK button of cinfirm alert OK btn. Means my `onclick="btnsave_Click"` event also call and my data get save on confirm message OK btn.

Comment: Don't you need to change the return condition, if he says ok .. you wanna return true rite

Comment: i got the ans. just i changes the java script and added the following line    if (document.getElementById("<%=isDirty.ClientID %>").value != document.getElementById("<%=txbText.ClientID %>").value) {
           var ssave = window.confirm('Your changes are not saved. Do you want to save your changes before you exit.')
           if (ssave == true) {
               document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click();
               return false;
           }
           else
               return true;
             }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change something in javascript

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=isDirty.ClientID %>").value != document.getElementById("<%=txbText.ClientID %>").value) 
{ 
  var ssave = window.confirm('Your changes are not saved. Do you want to save your changes before you exit.') 
if (ssave == true) 
{ 
  document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click(); 
  return false; 
} 
  else return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOK" Text="OK" OnClientClick="Javascript:return confirm('Your Message')" OnClick="btnOK_Click" />
```

Comment: i don't want to call my javascript on btn click of same page... i am checking the save change data on some other page, i am calling change value function on some other page onclientclick on the btn